# What are document and corpus in tf-idf?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, vectorization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

tf-idf = term frequency * inverse document frequency

***term frequency*** is defined as the count of a term in a document.

***inverse document frequency*** is defined as the total number of documents divided by the number of documents containing the word.

The formula above may vary, but that is the big picture.
Now, supposing I have a data set containing a list of 1 million sentences:

1) Is a document an entry in the data set?

2) Is the entire data set the corpus?

The question somehow relates to [1], but the answers did not help me understand the concept for a real data set.

Thank you.

[1] [What does "document" mean in a NLP context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749471/what-does-document-mean-in-a-nlp-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, if the sentences are unrelated, call each sentence a "document".

In some more detail, TF means a term is frequent in the current sample (to avoid the term "document"). DF indicates that a term is frequent in every sample. The quotient TF/DF, then, returns a high number for terms which are rare in the entire collection -- suggesting they are significant -- and a low number for terms which are common.